# Regular Expression for integer values in ios -accepts more than one sign?

Tags: iphone, ios, regex

```
NSRegularExpression* regExp = [[NSRegularExpression alloc]
   initWithPattern:@"^[-+s]*[0-9s]+$"` options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
    error:nil];
```

I used above expression. but it accepts the `+` and `-` values. but the problem is, it accepts more than one sign before the integer number.

```
  1)+++++12
  2)--++12
```

these cases are also accepted.

What can use , it should accept only one sign before integer?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't understand why you have 's' in your character groups, what is the reason for that?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for `@"^[-+]?[0-9]+$"`.

---

***update***

I think you are using 's' to match whitespace. That will not work.

`@"^\\s*[-+]?\\s*[0-9]+\\s*$"` will match whitespace before the plus/minus, between the plus/minus and the digits, and after the digits.

---

***NOTE***: a `?` matches 0 or 1 of the previous groups, in this case [-+].

---

***UPDATE***: Thanks @ValeriyVan for suggesting a fix for a critical issue is my whitespace code. I don't know why the community rejected your edit.

Comment: Thanks @JefferyThomas. This community's reject and your edit acceptance reminds all of us that majority can't be always true.

Answer (score 1):

Following code for the checking the integer values.

```
- (BOOL) validateIntegerValue: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *Regex = @"^[+-]{0,1}[0-9]+$";
    NSPredicate *intTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", Regex];
    return [intTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```